# Need to save variables for my onClick

Tags: java, android, button, buttonclick

```
for ( int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++ )
    {
        Button btn = new Button( this );
        btn.setText( guideStep.getResponse( i ).getTitle() );
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                try
                {
                    //NextStep(guideStep.getStep(), guideStep.getSession(), guideStep.getResponse( i ).getId() );
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView( btn );
    }
```

Looking at the following code. I am adding buttons dynamically to my linear layout. I need to, dynamically aswell, change the onClick event for each button. For that, I need the counter from the loop and some way to save my guideStep object, from without the loop aswell.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I need to call a method with my onClick, but I need information about the button I clicked to send with it. Information I can only get from objects instantiated outside the scope of the onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++ )
{
     final int id = i; // save your variable

     ...
     try
     {
       NextStep(guideStep.getStep(), guideStep.getSession(), 
            guideStep.getResponse( id ).getId() ); // use it
     }
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTag(your_id)` method on your button and then get the id back with `getTag()` method in your `OnClick`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++ )
{
    final int fin_i = i;
    ...
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
           // Use fin_i 
        });
    ...
}
```